# Var Dump in variable

Tags: php, api, curl

I have an API in PHP. If you have any error it returns true and if not it returns false. I'm capturing that like this:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost/api/v1/register");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And I can print it like that:

```
var_dump($response);
```

Right now, in a test, it returned this:

> string(4) "true"

How can I capture the true or false on a variable to use on an if for instance?

Comment: `$response` already contains true ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow on from Rizier123, it looks like `$response` contains the string true rather than the boolean true. And I believe PHP also considered a string containing the word false to be "true" in a boolean sense because it's not empty or a value of 0.

So maybe just do this:

`$responseValue = ($response === 'true') ? true : false;`

And then use `$responseValue` in your if statement?

Comment: I already knew that. It was a dumb problem with the if. I forgot one `=` sign. So I just had one, instead of two. I will give you points for the answwer anyways,